# throw error code with 'return next(err);'

Tags: node.js, express

How do I go about specifying the error code with a return next(err) statement so that I can display it in my catch all middleware?

```
var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
var fs = require("fs");
var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    // simulate 404 error
    fs.readFile("foo.txt", "utf8", function(error, data) {
      if(error) {
        next(new Error('Aiiii caramba'));
      }
    });

});

/* Error Handling (gotta catch 'em all) */
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500)
    .render('error', { 
    status: req.status,
    error: err
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening...');
})
```

The Error object doesn't acccept an argument for error code.
I also tried setting the response status before returning next... to no avail.

```
res.status(404); return next(err);
```

No matter what I do, I get error 500.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: If you want your `Error ` object to have a `status` property, then why not just set a `status` property on the `Error` object before passing it into `next`? Is that the answer to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason why `Error` should have a `status` property. If you want it, you have to craft your own error and let it inherit from `Error`.

In ES6 this can be done as follows:

```
class NotFound extends Error {
    constructor(message) {
        super(message);
        this.status = 404;
    }
}
```

If you are stuck with ES5, you can instead use the `util` module provided with node:

```
var util = require('util');

function NotFound(message) {
    Error.call(this);
    this.message = message;
    this.status = 404;
}

util.inherits(NotFound, Error);
```

Now, you can throw your custom error as `next(new NotFound('Aiiii caramba'));`. Arguably, `NotFound('Aiiii caramba')` expresses in a clear way the kind of encountered error.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with your error handling after the middlewares:

```
/* Error Handling (gotta catch 'em all) */
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500)
    .render('error', { 
    status: req.status,
    error: err
  });
});
```

you have there the line: `res.status(err.status || 500)` and since your error object does not have a status field, it is always assigned to 500

Comment: Thank you Nir. I understand why it gets the 500... I should have been more clearer: How do I pass it a different error code?